# Magento Fatal Error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

With a module I added an custom customer attribute. 
When a client is logged in and want to edit their account information or want to change their password on frontend the following error comes up:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Log' not found in /app/code/community/Amar/Profile/Model/Customer/Attribute.php on line 49
```

I build this website local and uploaded it to the server.
On the local environment this error is not showing up, this error only showing up on the server.

I think it has to do something with file permissions.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Change extension eq: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-attribute-1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem has been solved.

On the live server there was another PHP version which was not compatible with the extension.

Answer (score 0):

For me a function `loadByCode()` causes the issue, I have renamed it and it is working fine. We should not use `generic method names` in custom modules.

The function is in `\app\code\community\Amar\Profile\Model\Customer\Attribute.php file.`